# Dimension of the loss function and gradients for adversarial example

Tags: python, keras

I was working on some adversarial problem with mnist database. I was trying to find the gradient value for each pixel.For that, I  calculated the categorical_crossentropy loss between mnist_model.input and target_number (target_number was first one hot encoded and then converted to a Keras variable) and the gradients. The dimension of my loss function is 28 by 28 by 10 and gradients are 28 by 28 by 1. I am not sure how the codes are working.
Here is the following code,

```
target = to_categorical(target_number)
print(target)
target_variable = K.variable(target)
loss = keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy(mnist_model.input, target_variable)
gradients = K.gradients(loss, mnist_model.input)
get_grad_values = K.function([mnist_model.input], gradients)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you expecting to happen and what actually does happen?

Comment: I just wanted an expression how the dimension of the loss function is 28*28*10 and how it is coming down to 28*28*1 after using K.gradients

Comment: Why do you calculate the loss between the model's *input* and the target? The loss should be between the model's output and the target, no? The loss should be just a single number. Then you can take the gradient of the loss w.r.t. the model's inputs to figure out how changing each input pixel will bring the output closer to the desired target.

Comment: This was an example code which worked pretty well but I need explanation. The reason for using model input, I believe, is first to find the loss and then to find the gradient for each pixel. But anyway, your question is pretty much justified.

Comment: If you ask specific questions, I'm happy to try answering them.

Comment: Could you please explain be is there any broadcasting going on to match the dimension of the loss function? That may be a probable reason for getting the 28*28*10 dimension of the loss function.

Comment: I still don't understand why you compute the loss function comparing the model's _inputs_ to the desired _target_. The loss should be computed by comparing the model's _output_ to the target. Have a look at the [TensorFlow implementation of `keras.metrics.categorical_crossentropy`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3527) to understand what's going on.